# How to allow user to make edits to an array

Tags: java, arrays, input, edit

I must create 3 arrays, one to hold 5 product IDs, one to hold 5 product prices, and one to hold 5 product inventories. I need a method to print all the product IDs, print all product prices, and print all the inventories. I need a method to allow user to make edits to any of the product IDs, product prices, or inventories  (this is the method I am struggling with). After each edit is made I must reprint all the data. I also need a method to print all the correct data after all the edits are made and an extra column, the total price for each product and the overall price. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Inventory {
d   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] productIDArray = new String[5];
        double[] priceArray = new double[5];
        int[] inventoryArray = new int[5];


        input(productIDArray, priceArray, inventoryArray);
        print(productIDArray, priceArray, inventoryArray);
        edit(productIDArray, priceArray, inventoryArray);

    }

    public static void input (String[] productIDArray, double[] priceArray, int[] inventoryArray) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the product ID, the price and inventory: ");
            productIDArray[i] = input.next();
            priceArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
            inventoryArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        }       
    }


    public static void print (String[] productIDArray, double[] priceArray, 
    int[] inventoryArray) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(productIDArray[i]);
            System.out.println(priceArray[i]);
            System.out.println(inventoryArray[i]);
        }


    }


     public static void edit (String[] productIDArray, double[] priceArray, int[] inventoryArray) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int whatToEdit = 0;
         String oldProductID = " ";
         String newProductID = " ";
         double oldPrice = 0;
         double newPrice = 0;
         int oldInventory = 0;
         int newInventory = 0;
         String yesNo = " ";

         while (true) {
             System.out.print("Do you want to make an edit? (Y/N)");
             if (yesNo = y.toUppercase) {
                 System.out.print("Enter what you want to edit: ");
                 System.out.print("Do you want to edit a product ID (1), price (2), or  
                 inventory (3)? ");
                 whatToEdit = input.nextInt();
                 if (whatToEdit == 1) {
                     System.out.print("Enter the product ID you want to edit and the edit: ");
                     productID = input.next();  
                     newProductID = input.next();
                     productIDArray[product] = newProductID;     
                 } else if (whatToEdit == 2) {
                     System.out.print("Enter the price you want to edit and the edit: ");
                     oldPrice = input.nextDouble();
                     newPrice = input.nextDouble();
                     priceArray[oldPrice] = newPrice;
                 } else if (whatToEdit == 3) {
                     System.out.print("Enter the inventory you want to edit and the edit: ");
                     oldInventory = input.nextInt();
                     newPrice = input.nextInt();
                     inventoryArray[oldInventory] = newInventory;
                 }
             }  
        } else if (yesNo == n.toUppercase) {
            break;
        }
        print(productIDArray, priceArray, inventoryArray);
    }

    public static void totalPrice (String[] productIDArray, double[] priceArray, int[] inventoryArray) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: On Stackoverlow you usually don't get code written for you. Let us know what the problem with your approach is, where there are errors etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am just not sure how to make the edits.

Comment: "_After each edit is made I must reprint all the data (this is the method I am struggling with)_" You already have a print method, just call it each time you do an edit. What is the issue?

Comment: My fault, I meant that I am struggling with making the edits. Reprinting the data will not be an issues.

Comment: @Jolly_Jimmy make sure to [edit] your question to incorporate that. Not everybody coming here will read all the coments

Answer (score 0):

First check which array they want to edit. Then check which part of the array they want to change. You then just take the users input for which piece of the array and the new value for that piece.

Lets say they chose inventory array. Get input for which part of array and then the number to replace it with.

```
 inventoryArray[usersinput] = //Users next inputted number they want to replace it with
```

EDIT: 
To check which array they want to edit you could do something like this.

```
    System.out.print("Enter 1 for product array, 2 for price array, and 3 for inventory: ");
```

Then read the users input again and use an if or switch statement to decide what to do with whichever array they chose.

EDIT 2:
Problems with your compare and toUppercase. I can't find where your defining the variable 'y' which you are using with your toUpperCase(). So you also need to define that somewhere.

```
if (yesNo.equals(y.toUppercase()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, how would i check which array they want to edit?

Comment: I edited my answer to help explain how you could go about allowing them to chose an array.

Comment: I added what i did to the code above, I am not sure if it is correct or not yet.

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. Let me know if it works or you get any errors you cant fix!

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited the code but i am getting a few errors.           error: cannot find symbol
                        yesNo = input.next().toUpperCase;                                         Inventory.java:61: error: incomparable types: Scanner and String
                if (input == "Y") {
                          ^                                                                                             There is more but i cant make this any longer.

Comment: I fixed a few errors, but now I have 3 left. Inventory.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
                        yesNo = input.next().toUpperCase;
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable toUpperCase
  location: class String
Inventory.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
                    productIDArray[oldproductID] = newProductID;
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable oldproductID
  location: class Inventory
Inventory.java:75: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
priceArray[oldPrice] = newPrice;

Comment: I made another edit. You should probably mark this as answered and make a new question if you have any more bugs you need fixing! This thread is getting a little jumbled with multiple questions going on.